# Reading output from console through asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this code to pass two numbers as input to an .exe of a C program file through asp.net and after that trying to read the output from console. I am having problem to read any output from the console.

My asp.net code is.

string returnvalue;

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.FileName = ("C:\\Users\\...\\noname01.exe");
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.Start();
Thread.Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait("1");
Thread.Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait("~");
Thread.Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait("2");
Thread.Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait("~");
Thread.Sleep(500);

StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;

returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();

System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Hussain\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\WebSites\\WebSite4\\Data\\StudentOutput.txt");
file.WriteLine(returnvalue);
```

My C code to which am passing inputs is.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
    int a, b, c;

    printf("Enter two numbers to add\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

    c = a + b;

    printf("Sum of entered numbers = %d\n",c);

    return 0;
    }
```

Any kind of help required.

Comment: And ... what's the problem?

Comment: i cant read any output from console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if SendKeys works in this case as the console window is hidden and SendKeys is supposed to write to the active window and the child process windw is hidden, but if you use `StandardInput.WriteLine` to send data to the child process it should work.

This code works and creates a file `AdderOutput.txt` with the following content:

> Enter two numbers to add 
>   Sum of entered numbers = 3

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string returnvalue;

            Process p = new Process();

            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = ("D:\\adder.exe");
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("1");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("2");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;
            returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();

            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\AdderOutput.txt");
            file.WriteLine(returnvalue);
            file.Flush();
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

It might not be the best solution - it's been a while since I did C# - but it seems to work. The `adder.exe`used is the C program from your code.

Comment: it does not pass any input. it just opens the .exe file although the console window is hidden.

Comment: @AdilShafiq I'm not sure I understand you, are you saying my program doesn't work or is there some other problem?

Comment: using write line do not pass the input instead it opens the exe in console and ask for input by keyboard.

Comment: @AdilShafiq That's not how the application behaves when I run it. When I execute the ConsoleApplication1.exe built from the code in my answer it opens a command window, writes to the file and exits. Is that not what happens when you try it?

Comment: no it just opens exe file when i run it. the code which i have posted passes the input but only problem is that it does not read the output.

Comment: @AdilShafiq Are you sure the output isn't written to the text file?

Comment: yeah my text file of output remains empty.

Comment: @AdilShafiq That's odd, it works for me. Did you compile my sample code as I posted it, changing only the paths to the output file and the C executable?

Comment: actually am doing it in webform asp.net

Comment: @AdilShafiq That kind of changes things I guess. You should update your question to reflect that and also tag it with tags for asp.net and webform.